# How write collection columns values to columns in table in word document in blueprism

Tags: collections, cpu-word, vbo, blueprism

I am working in blueprism and I have to loop through a collection to write back certain columns in the collection to a word file (using Business Object: MS Word VBO, and Action: Type Text). The current setup writes the collection columns values at the beginning of the word file. I would like to have those collection columns to be written in a specific table that already exists in my word template file. How can I achieve that?

Current process:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp4ng.png)

The current way the collection column values are written in word file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW7RN.png)

Comment: Why would you use an action called "*Type Text*" when the default MS Word VBO includes the actions `Add Table Row` and `Set Table Cell Value`...? Wouldn't those fit your use case much better than just arbitrarily "[typing] text"?

Comment: You are absolutely right! I tried `Set Table Cell Value` and it solved my problem. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score -1):

I tried `Set Table Cell Value` and it solved my problem.